# Reading from a file into an array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, file, char, scanf

I'm trying to read a list of strings from a file to an array.
in file it looks like this

```
ItemOne
ItemTwo
ItemThree etc.
```

I declared an array as:

```
char** array;
```

and file as:

```
FILE *read;
```

This is what I came up with:

```
{
    i = 0;
    printf("Type in the name of the file\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    read = fopen(name, "r");
    if (read == NULL)
    {
        perror("Doesn't work");
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        array = malloc(100 * sizeof(*array));
        while (!feof(read))
        {
            array[i] = malloc(32 * sizeof(*array[i]));
            fscanf(read, "%s", &array[i]);
            i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Tt compiles, but when I try to display the array it's empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code that you use to display the data.

Comment: you have obviously omitted part of your code.

Comment: And casted the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: If I understand your code, your second `sizeof` should just be `char`. It's clearer. One more thing: Unless you're actually allocating memory dynamically, don't use `malloc`. You're array can only store 100 strings, which themselves can only store 32 characters. Fix that, and you'll be a lot happier.

Comment: display an array:
`void display(char** tab, int size){
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    printf("%d.\t%s\n", i, tab[i]);
   }
}`

I just realized i didn't add new size of that array after reading from a file, but it still doesn't work. It adds every item in the first place in tha array and displays symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    while (!feof(read))
    {
        array[i] = malloc(32 * sizeof(*array[i]));
        fscanf(read, "%s", array[i]); //You should pass a pointer to a pointer to array of chars
        i++;
    }
```

I hope it'll work...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long GetFileSize(FILE *fp){
    long fsize = 0;

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp); 
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);//reset stream position!!

    return fsize;
}

char *ReadToEnd(const char *filepath){
    FILE *fp;
    long fsize;
    char *buff;

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filepath, "rb"))){
        perror("file cannot open at ReadToEnd\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fsize=GetFileSize(fp);
    buff=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*fsize+1);
    fread(buff, sizeof(char), fsize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    buff[fsize]='\0';

    return buff;
}

char** split(const char *str, const char *delimiter, size_t *len){
    char *text, *p, *first, **array;
    int c;
    char** ret;

    *len = 0;
    text=strdup(str);
    if(text==NULL) return NULL;
    for(c=0,p=text;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, delimiter));p=NULL, c++)//count item
        if(c==0) first=p; //first token top

    ret=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*c+1);//+1 for NULL
    if(ret==NULL){
        free(text);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(text, str+(first-text));//skip until top token
    array=ret;

    for(p=text;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, delimiter));p=NULL){
        *array++=strdup(p);
    }
    *array=NULL;
    *len=c;
    free(text);
    return ret;
}

void free4split(char** sa){
    char **array=sa;

    if(sa!=NULL){
        while(*sa)
            free(*sa++);//for string
        free(array);    //for array
    }
}

int main(){
    char *text, **lines;
    size_t line_count;

    text=ReadToEnd("data.txt");
    lines=split(text, "\r\n", &line_count);
    free(text);
    {   //test print
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<line_count;++i)
            printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
    }
    free4split(lines);

    return 0;
}
```